# App Store will not update applications on iOS 13.2.3, iPadOS 13.2.3 or macOS 10.15.1

Tags: macos, ios, ios-appstore, software-update

It happened since 13.2.2 and I thought maybe this recent 13.2.3 could fix it but I was wrong. When I tap "Update" the indicator spins for a short period and then "Update" reappears. I have called Appel Support 3-4 times and they could not help. I have done everything I could think of, rebooting, signing out from App Store and iCloud. Even I tried restoring iPad. I have even tried another Apple ID to update an existing app in vain. I also tried changing payment detail. Nothing has worked. I can download new apps and reinstall previous purchases though. One las hope for me to find out the reason was looking into the logs (for iOS from Apple Configurator, and Console app for macOS) after hitting update. I share theme and hope someone can help.

iPad logs: https://paste.ee/p/eDCV5

MacBook logs: https://paste.ee/p/LNdOn

Comment: I mentioned that, you'd not like to delete and reinstall 10 apps everyday

Comment: okay, i have on both iOS and iPadOS

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my iphone XS Max starting with ios 13.1.3. I updated to 13.2.2 but that didn’t help. I restored my phone from backup yesterday and still have the same issue.

Comment: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/merged-ios-13-2-2-app-updates-stuck-on-waiting.2210793/page-3